# Javascript for loop skipping a rotation inside matrix

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix, rotation, skip

I have been pounding my head for a while now, trying to figure out why my for loops skips a rotation in my matrix. I am trying to make it print out [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]], that being the whole matrix.

```
function solve(args)
{
    let arr = args[0].split(' ').map(Number),
        rows = +arr[0],
        cols = +arr[1];

    let matrix = new Array(rows);
    matrix.fill();
    for (let i in matrix)
    {
        matrix[i] = new Array(cols);
    }

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        matrix[row][0] = Math.pow(2, row);
        for (let col = matrix[row][0]; col < cols; col++)
        {
            matrix[row][col] = +col + 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(matrix);
}

solve([
  '3 5'  
]);
```

P.S. I tried this too:

```
for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        matrix[row][0] = Math.pow(2, row);
        for (let col = matrix[row][0]; col < cols; col++)
        {
            matrix[row][col] = +col + matrix[row][0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really want the third row to look like this: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  or rather something like this: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]   ?

Comment: Exactly the same as I wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you. While starting with a certain value as first element (*matrix[row][0]*) you can increment each row by 1 iteratively:

```
function solve(args)
{
  let arr = args[0].split(' '),
  rows = +arr[0],
  cols = +arr[1];
  let matrix = new Array(rows);
  matrix.fill();
  for (let i in matrix)
  {
    matrix[i] = new Array(cols);
  }
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    matrix[row][0] = Math.pow(2, row);
    for (let col = 1; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
      matrix[row][col] = col + matrix[row][0];
    }
  }
  console.log(matrix);
  return matrix;
}

solve([
'3 5'
]);
```

Comment: Have a look on this answer.

Comment: PS: little improvements done to make it a bit more efficient.